# Turning on accept/reject options in wget changes file download behavior

Tags: wget

I am trying to connect to a Sharepoint site and fetch Excel workbooks from a specific folder. The issues I am having are mainly that wget is fetching files from every single level. Here is the code I am using:

```
wget --http-user='someuser' --http-password="somepassword" -r -l 1 --no-remove-listing 
"http://somehost.com/lvl1/lvl2/lvl3/lvl4/lvl5/lvl6/" -nd --cut-dirs 5 --random-wait
```

Where lvl6 is the directory in which my files sit. What this command does is it pulls all the files under lvl1 to lvl6. I tried getting around this by adding

```
--accept xlsx --reject aspx
```

to the end of the command (since most extraneous files are aspx). But weirdly, this just causes wget to fetch just one index.html file instead.

So far, I have tried changing the number of recursive levels (0 to 20), adding --no-parent, and some other options that did not work out. Any ideas?